# How to insertsort array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, insert

How can I sort an array of strings with the insertion sort algorithm? I actually have 3 arrays of strings --> `a`,`b`,`c` and I want to sort all of them parallel **based on array a**. I've written the code which I think is correct, but gives an error:

```
int main() {

/* the insertsort call is */ InsertSort (count, A, B, C);
/* A, B, and C are arrays of strings */
/* count is the size of the array */

}

void InsertSort (int n, char *a[17], char *b[17], char *c[5]){
char *temp = malloc(17);
char *temp1 = malloc(17);
char *temp2 = malloc(5);
    int i, j;
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        j=i-1;
        while (j>=0 && strcmp(a[j],a[j+1])<0) {
            strcpy(temp, a[j]);
            strcpy(a[j], a[j+1]);
            strcpy(a[j+1], temp);

            strcpy(temp1, b[j]);
            strcpy(b[j], b[j+1]);
            strcpy(b[j+1], temp1);

            strcpy(temp2, c[j]);
            strcpy(c[j], c[j+1]);
            strcpy(c[j+1], temp2);
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Please add the call to `InsertSort` including the definition of the passed argumenty.

Comment: You know `strcpy` does not allocate any memory? Passing it an uninitialised pointer (`temp`) is UB.

Comment: I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: I think.. the article wasn't for my situation... Anyway, I still can't figure it out

Comment: You're trying to sort three arrays of `char*`, but only one of them (`A`) is actually used for keying the sort, right? swaps that happen while sorting `A` should be done for the same indexes in `B` and `C`, is that right? And fwiw, no dynamic allocation should be needed for this beyond that already done for A, B, and C respectively.

Comment: Yes, all you said is right, so what do you propose?